# Testing imageField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want test my view, but I don't know how I can send image in request. I mean, I have model like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

I have serializers:

```
class RecieverSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta():
        fields = ('id', 'email')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'username' : {'validators':[]}
        }

class ItemSerializer(serialisers.ModelSerializer):
    reciever = RecieverSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta():
        model = Item
        fields = ('text', 'image')
```

View:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Item
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    queryset = []
```

How I can send data to server? If i try json:

```
{ 
    "text": "123456",
    "reciever":[
        {"id":1, "email":"qwe@qwe.qwe"},
        {"id":2, "email":"asd@asd.asd"}
     ],
    "image" : http://someurl.com/way/image.jpg
}
```

Rest framework returns: `JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded`

Comment: Isn't there missing some quotes for the image url? You can try just passing the path `way/image.jpg` to the image field and django will try to concat the MEDIA_URL or MEDIA_ROOT + the imagefield path

Answer (score 0):

Just try this,
Edit `ItemSerializer` like this.

```
class ItemSerializer(serialisers.ModelSerializer):
    reciever = RecieverSerializer(many=True)
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_image_url')

    class Meta():
        model = Item
        fields = ('text', 'image')

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        if obj.image:
            return self.context['request'].build_absolute_uri(obj.image.url)
```